# Trying to use a function to concatenate columns

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a function to concatenate two columns and call that function into a table. I have tried several different approaches. I have stripped it down as far as I can to build on it.

Some of the code is missing to create the detailed table, the problem I am having is to concatenate the first and last name and then call it into my table. I would like to concatenate inside the table, but sadly this is for a class so I have to make it into a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION customer_name(first_name varchar, last_name varchar)
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
SELECT
first_name || ' ' || last_name
RETURN;
END; $$

INSERT INTO Detailed(
customer_id,
rental_date,
return_date,
customer_name)
SELECT
customer_id,
rental_date,
return_date,
customer_name(first_name, last_name)
FROM customer
INNER JOIN rental USING(customer_id);
```

Comment: Your function does not return concatenated names. And you should select INTO. Or do it without selecting at all: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/o6xCHL80).

Comment: Or you may use `sql` language and that way the function returns the result of your select statement.

Comment: Why don’t you use the standard function concat_ws() ?